# Unable to run docker image with findspark.init

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I've created a docker image of a program that has the `findspark.init()` function in it. The program runs well on the local machine. When I try to run the image with `docker run -p 5000:5000 imgname:latest`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 37, in <module>
    findspark.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/findspark.py", line 129, in init
    spark_home = find()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/findspark.py", line 35, in find
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).
```

Can anyone suggest a way around this problem? When I try to make the program without the findspark function, I'm getting other errors related to Spark. This is my dockerfile:

```
#Use python as base image
FROM python:3.8

#Use working dir app
WORKDIR /app

#Copy contents of current dir to /app
ADD . /app

#Install required packages
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

#Open port 5000
EXPOSE 5000

#Set environment variable
ENV NAME analytic

#Run python program
CMD python app.py
```

Here is the part of the code where the image is stalling:

```
    ### multiple lines of importing libraries and then    
    # Spark imports
    import findspark
    findspark.init()
    
    import pyspark
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

The requirements.txt file can be seen on this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rsegumcqbwcecr/requirements.txt?dl=0).

Comment: can you share your `requirements.txt` file? the relevant snippet of `app.py`?

Comment: + note that Spark provides a docker image build script, you can see more info in my post, go to Appendix, part 1: https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebook-spark-on-kubernetes-880af7e06351

Comment: @ItayB added code and requirements.txt link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark requires Java even if you're running pyspark, so you need to install java in your image.
In addition, if you're still using `findspark` you can specify the `SPARK_HOME` directory as well:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-jre
ENV SPARK_HOME /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark
```

To summarize, your `Dockerfile` should look like:

```
#Use python as base image
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-jre

#Use working dir app
WORKDIR /app

#Copy contents of current dir to /app
ADD . /app

#Install required packages
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

#Open port 5000
EXPOSE 5000

#Set environment variable
ENV NAME analytic
ENV SPARK_HOME /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark

#Run python program
CMD python app.py
```

Comment: Thanks, with this the image is running but this being a Flask app, the templates are not loading. Do you know what could be the problem here?

Comment: Try to open a different question with the details and I'll try to assist :)